# split a df column and perform subtraction

Tags: r

I have a df with 4 columns and 4th column is actually a character string with numbers separated by ",".

```
chrom   peakStart      peakEnd  CpGPos
chr10   117952993    117953593  111,304,470,566,577
chr10   25219070      25219670  92,162,301,354,385,450,483
chr10   4333197    4333797  241,488,493,502,547,597
chr10   64090001      64090601  265,269,282,439,465,499,515,527,585,594
chr10   68541389      68541989  503,511,525
chr10   84836010      84836610  18,69,92,139,344,403,488
```

I would like to split the 4th column by "," and then subtract each value from 300 and populate the minimum of all that in a new column. e.g

```
chrom   peakStart      peakEnd  CpGPos minimumDis
chr10   117952993    117953593  111,304,470,566,577 -4
```

I am not able to properly split to get numeric vector on which I can run some operations. Any pointers are helpful.

ST

Comment: `300 - c(111, 304, 470, 566, 577)` gives `c(189, -4, -170, -266, -277)`, why did you pick -4 out of that?

Comment: @r2evans he probably wants the smallest absolute distance.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I am looking for smallest absolute distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df$new_col <- sapply(strsplit(df$col4, split = ","), function(x) 300 - min(as.numeric(x)))
```

If you're looking for the smallest absolute distance, you can modify things accordingly:

```
    df$new_col <- sapply(strsplit(df$col4, split = ","), function(x) min(abs(300 - as.numeric(x))))
```

or (to keep the signs)

```
df$new_col <- sapply(strsplit(df$col4, split = ","), function(x) {
  tmp <- 300 - as.numeric(x)
  sign(tmp[which.min(abs(tmp))]) * min(abs(tmp))
})
```

(Updated to reflect correction to `sign` from  Rui Barradas)

Comment: Two notes: 1) The column name is `CpGPos`, not `col4`. 2) `sign(tmp)` is a vector of the same length as `tmp` so it's better to do `sign(tmp[which.min(abs(tmp))]) * min(abs(tmp))`, and avoid returning a list with members of different lengths. Anyway, upvote.

Comment: Awesome! The second solutions works perfectly. Just to indicate: last solution is filling the new col with multiple values (all minimum diff). So, instead of having one value in new col there are multiple values.

Comment: Good points, Rui Barradas.  If I was running this, I would have caught the sign(tmp) issue.  I'll adjust the answer accordingly.